# Bind Java program to Cocoa interface

Tags: java, objective-c, eclipse, model-view-controller, macos

would it be possible to bind a Java application to a Cocoa graphical interface?

I'm working in Eclipse right now, on my mac, and am wondering if Interface Builder could be used to construct a new interface so that I don't have to look at Swing all day.

Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Rococoa](http://code.google.com/p/rococoa/).  It's a great Java-Cocoa compatibility layer that's built on top of [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/).

If you don't find what you are looking for in the documentation, try the mailing list.  The Rococoa developers are very helpful.

P.S.  I'm not a Cocoa/Objective-C expert, but the section on "[NIB loading](http://code.google.com/p/rococoa/wiki/NIBLoading)" might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Some good (ANCIENT) historical info here (written 2002):

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000024.php

The original Java/Cocoa bridge (since Mac OS X 10.0) became marked deprecated in 10.4, and is considered unusable.  The Rococoa answer above is basically your best bet. Just thought I'd chime in with the historical note.

Comment: In addition, the Java/Cocoa bridge was completely removed from Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Objective-C Bridge](https://github.com/shannah/Java-Objective-C-Bridge) provides a simpler and lighter-weight mechanism (than Rococoa) for accessing Objective-C APIs.  It doesn't require you to generate any stub wrapper classes.  It just provides a "Proxy" class for accessing the Objective-C API at runtime.

Some examples:

- [Loading a NIB file with a WebView](https://github.com/shannah/Java-Objective-C-Bridge/blob/master/java/test/ca/weblite/objc/TestWebView.java)
- [Loading a NIB file](https://github.com/shannah/Java-Objective-C-Bridge/blob/master/java/test/ca/weblite/objc/LoadNibSample.java)
- [An NSSavePanel wrapper](https://github.com/shannah/Java-Objective-C-Bridge/blob/master/java/test/ca/weblite/objc/NSSavePanelSample.java)
- [Accessing NSProcessInfo from Java to solve App Nap problem](https://github.com/shannah/Java-Objective-C-Bridge/blob/master/java/test/ca/weblite/objc/NSProcessInfoUtils.java)

Full disclosure:  I'm the author of the Java-Objective-C bridge